# AngularJS ng-repeat get data from JSON

Tags: angularjs, json

I got a problem on getting data from `ng-repeat`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in records">
    <td>{{x.id}}</td>
    <td>{{x.title}}</td>
    <td>{{x.year}}</td>
    <td>{{x.note}}</td>
</tr>
```

The `{{x.id}}` is the `tt0013158` I want to get from the JSON.

Here is the JSON:

```
{"result":{
    "tt0013158":{
        "note":"",
        "title":"The Frozen North",
        "year":"1922"
    },
    "tt1605783":{
        "note":"",
        "title":"Midnight in Paris",
         "year":"2011"
    }
}}
```

I can get the note, title and year correctly. But how can I get the id (such as `tt0013158`) from the JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no notion in javascript (or angular) that tt0013158 in the sample above would be the object's id. It's just a key in a map.

I believe this should do the trick:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, x) in records.result">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td>{{x.title}}</td>
    <td>{{x.year}}</td>
    <td>{{x.note}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use (key,value) syntax :

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data in records.result">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td>{{value.id}}</td>
    <td>{{value.title}}</td>
    <td>{{value.year}}</td>
    <td>{{value.note}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach to iterate through ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in records">
<td>{{item.id}}</td>
<td>{{item.note}}</td>
<td>{{item.title}}</td>
<td>{{item.year}}</td>
</tr>
```